Execute onSessionEnded when closed browser but not refresh
I have the following chunk in my Shiny app
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    
    dbDisconnect(database)
  })

How can I execute it when the app is closed but not when hitting the refresh button?

Call onStop outside the server function or use this pattern.
